# if else condition is not executed properly

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have a condition where if the user inputs a **negative number or a number which is more than 100, or a string**, an error message should be printed "That wasn't a valid percentage, I need a number between 0-100. Try again." and ask the user to reenter a valid number. and if the user decided to just enter, all the input should be calculated and printed the average amount.

```java
   public static void main(String[ ] args) {
   
      int count = 0; //count to stop loop
       
      double[ ] aGrade = new double[SIZE]; 
      String input = new String("");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      double total = 0; 
      int gTotal = aGrade.length; 
      boolean exit = false; 
      while ((count < SIZE) && (!exit)) {
      
         System.out.print("Enter number " + (count + 1) + ": " + "\n");
         try {
            input = scan.nextLine();
         
            if (Double.parseDouble(input) > 0 && Double.parseDouble(input) < 100) {
               aGrade[count] = Double.parseDouble(input); //put into the array
               count++; //only increment count if success

            } else 
               System.out.println("That wasn't a valid percentage,"
                  + " I need a number between 0-100. Try again.");
         
         } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            exit = true; //exit loop
         }
      }

      System.out.println("number of grades entered: " + count + "\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
      
      
      // print entered grade
         System.out.println("grade " + (i + 1) + ": " + aGrade[i]);   
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         total += aGrade[i]; 
      }
   // calculate and print the average
      System.out.println("\n" + "Average grade: " + total /count);
```

But when I run my code, if I input letters, it won't allow the user to reinput value but prints whatever is calculated. I think it is in my if-else statement, but I am not sure how

Comment: I fixed your markdown. You please fix the indentation.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you so much. I am new here so I do not know much yet to edit my post.

Comment: @LMF: Click on "Edit" below the post to edit. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for editing help.

Comment: Hint: what do you think `Double.parseDouble` does when you enter letters? What does your code do at that point? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. Also, 'Double.parseDouble' indicates to convert string to double

Comment: Yes, I know what `Double.parseDouble` does. But do you know what happens if you provide it with non-numeric input? And do you know how your code reacts to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we try to convert String to Double it will throw **java.lang.NumberFormatException**. So whenever you enter String or char at that time instead of else it will go to catch block. As per your code else block only executed when user enter negative number or grater then 100 number.

I updated your code. Please review it.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0; // count to stop loop

        double[] aGrade = new double[3];
        String input = new String("");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double total = 0;
        int gTotal = aGrade.length;
        boolean exit = false;
        while ((count < 3) && (!exit)) {

            System.out.print("Enter number " + (count + 1) + ": " + "\n");
            try {
                input = scan.nextLine();

                if (Double.parseDouble(input) > 0 && Double.parseDouble(input) < 100) {
                    aGrade[count] = Double.parseDouble(input); // put into the array
                    count++; // only increment count if success

                } else
                    System.out
                            .println("That wasn't a valid percentage," + " I need a number between 0-100. Try again.");

            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                nfe.printStackTrace();
                exit = true; // exit loop
            }
        }

        if (!exit) {
            System.out.println("number of grades entered: " + count + "\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                // print entered grade
                System.out.println("grade " + (i + 1) + ": " + aGrade[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                total += aGrade[i];
            }
            // calculate and print the average
            System.out.println("\n" + "Average grade: " + total / count);

        }else {
            System.out
            .println("That wasn't a valid percentage," + " I need a number between 0-100. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type letter as an input, you will never end up in your `else` part of the if statement since code inside `if` throws an exception and you are then inside `catch` part. Also, you wrote inside `catch` part, when `NumberFormatException` happens(when you enter letter instead of number), set `exit` to `true` and that is the reason why program don't let you type again after you input letter. Fix those things and it will work. Also, take a look at how to debug your program, learn that skill, it will help you to solve this kind of problems in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
     boolean ok = false;
     try {
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if ("".equals(input)) {
            ok = true;
            exit = true;
        } else if (Double.parseDouble(input) >= 0 && Double.parseDouble(input) <= 100) {
           aGrade[count] = Double.parseDouble(input); //put into the array
           count++; //only increment count if success
           ok = true;
        }
     } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // nothing
     }
     if (!ok) {
        System.out.println("That wasn't a valid percentage,"
              + " I need a number between 0-100. Try again.");
     }
```